# Square Connect can't subscribe to webhook notifications

Tags: webhooks, square-connect

I am following the instructions [here](http://corner.squareup.com/2014/12/webhooks-in-the-square-connect-api.html) on setting up webhook notifications for Square payments.  But when I execute the curl statement in step 5 to subscribe to my own merchant's payment notifications, I get the response:

```
{"type":"bad_request","message":"Request body is not an array of event types"}
```

The curl statement is

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" -d '{"event_types": ["PAYMENT_UPDATED"]}' https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/webhooks
```

Did they update the event type names?  I can't find any other documentation on webhooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops! Thanks for catching this error in the blog post, which I have now corrected. The format of the `curl` previously shown in step 5 had two errors:

1. The request body should simply have been the array of desired event types, such as:

   `["PAYMENT_UPDATED"]`

   With no JSON object surrounding it. The correct format is also shown in the [API documentation](http://docs.connect.squareup.com/#webhooks-overview).
2. The request was missing a `Content-Type: application/json` header. All requests to Connect API endpoints require this header.

The correct request looks like this, with your personal access token substituted where indicated:

`curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[\"PAYMENT_UPDATED\"]" https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/webhooks`

Comment: I'm still getting the exact same error.  Now I'm using: curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer MY_ACCESS_TOKEN" -d '["PAYMENT_UPDATED"]' https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/webhooks.  Just to double check, I did a GET on that endpoint, and it gives me an empty array.

Comment: Ah, the command in the blog post is also missing a required `Content-Type` header. I've updated the above answer accordingly, and will correct the blog post.